# Can't change text color to white

Tags: html, css

```css
.testfooter > .row > .col-lg-12 > .col-md-3 > .nav nav-pills nav-stacked > a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="testfooter">
  <br>
  <div style="padding-left:185px;" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Linkedin</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li><a href="#">Dentists</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Dermatologists</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Gynecologists</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Orthopedists</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Pediatricians</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to change the color of the links in my footer from green to white. But for some reason it's not changing the color.

Here is the html

```
<div class="testfooter">
  <br>
  <div style="padding-left:185px;" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Linkedin</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#">Dentists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dermatologists</a></li>      
          <li><a href="#">Gynecologists</a></li>          
          <li><a href="#">Orthopedists</a></li>          
          <li><a href="#">Pediatricians</a></li>          

        </ul>
      </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Here is the css I tried to use

```
.testfooter > .row > .col-lg-12 > .col-md-3 > .nav nav-pills nav-stacked >  a {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: For links you have to make color rules for all states (`:active`, `:visited`, etc)

Comment: This is not a specific answer to your question, for that see the answers, but do not use layout-specific classes such as `col-md-3` as part of selectors. It will break as soon as you decide to change your layout. If need be, add additional semantic classes to the elements in question and write selectors using those. As for your specific question, re-read your CSS tutorial on how to write selectors to target elements with multiple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are due to the fact that `.col-lg-12` and nav-pills and nav-stacked should both be `.nav-pills` and `.nav-stacked`.  Also, it would probably be easier to write this as:

```
.testfooter a {
    color: white;
}
```

Hope this helped, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing any class `.col-lg-12` in your HTML so that breaks your rule. Additionally, you are using the [Direct Child Selector (>)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) so you must also all the `<li>` to your rule. Finally you shouldn't have any spaces in `.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked`.

Here's a working example

```css
.testfooter { background-color: #DDD }
.testfooter > .row > .col-md-3 > .nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked > li > a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="testfooter">
  <br/>
  <div style="padding-left:185px;" class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Linkedin</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li><a href="#">Dentists</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dermatologists</a></li>      
          <li><a href="#">Gynecologists</a></li>          
          <li><a href="#">Orthopedists</a></li>          
          <li><a href="#">Pediatricians</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```